# How can I refine my query in a best way with optimum results (for large database)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I refine my query in a best way with optimum results (for large database tables) ?

See the tables structure and the query below

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Franchise](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL, 
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Franchise] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookingAgreements](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FranchiseId] [int] NOT NULL,   
    [ReservationId] [varchar](9) NULL,
    [RentalAgreementId] [varchar](9) NULL,  
    [AgreementStatus] [int] NULL,   
    [StatusId] [int] NULL,  
    [OrderNumber] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [ChargedDays] [decimal](18, 2) NULL,    
 CONSTRAINT [PK_BookingAgreements] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AgreementDrivers](
    [AgreementId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DriverId] [bigint] NOT NULL,       
    [FranchiseId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [StatusId] [int] NULL,
    [Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DriverPhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DriverTitle] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [DriverFirstName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [DriverSurname] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [DriverDOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [DriverCompanyName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [DriverCompanyDetails] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [DriverEmail] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [DriverSources] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DriverPostCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DriverHouse] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [DriverStreet] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [DriverVillage] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [DriverCountry] [int] NULL,
    [DriverCounty] [int] NULL,
    [DriverTown] [int] NULL,
    [DriverDetailTownName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [DriverDetailCountyName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [DriverCountryName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [LicenceCopyMade] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceDetailCountry] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [LicenceType] [int] NULL,
    [LicenceTestPassDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LicenceExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RenterId] [int] NULL,
    [MainDriverUserId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AgreementDrivers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AgreementRenters](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AgreementId] [int] NULL,
    [FranchiseId] [int] NULL,
    [isRenterAgreedAccHolder] [bit] NULL,
    [RenterTypeId] [int] NULL,
    [isHighRiskUser] [bit] NULL,
    [MainDriverId] [int] NULL,
    [RenterSources] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RenterTitle] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [RenterFirstName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [RenterSurname] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [RenterDOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [RenterPhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RenterEmail] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [RenterCompanyName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [RenterCompanyDetails] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [RenterCompanyAcNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LicencePostCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LicenceHouse] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [LicenceStreet] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [LicenceVillage] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LicenceCountry] [int] NULL,
    [LicenceCounty] [int] NULL,
    [LicenceTown] [int] NULL,
    [LicenceTownName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [LicenceCountyName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [LicenceCountryName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [LicenceNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LicenceDetails] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceType] [int] NULL,
    [LicenceIssuedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LicenceIssuedCountry] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LicenceTestPassDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LicenceExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LicenceSeen] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceWebCheck] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceETDSeen] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceCopyMade] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceGroups] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RenterLicenceIsUkAddress] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ContactPostCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactAddressType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactAddress1] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactAddress2] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactAddress3] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactCountry] [int] NULL,
    [ContactCounty] [int] NULL,
    [ContactTown] [int] NULL,
    [ContactMethod] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [RenterContactIsUkAddress] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ContactTownName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactCountyName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactCountryName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Occupation] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OccEmploymentType] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [OccName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [OccPhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OccPostcode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OccAddress1] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [OccAddress2] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [OccAddress3] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [OccCountry] [int] NULL,
    [OccCounty] [int] NULL,
    [OccTown] [int] NULL,
    [OccVerified] [bit] NULL,
    [RenterOccIsUkAddress] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [OccTownName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [OccCountyName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [OccCountryName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [RenterIdentification] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CoiInsuranceCompany] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CoiPolicyNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CoiContactName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CoiExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CoiPhone] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CoiCertificateCopy] [bit] NULL,
    [HighRiskUsrComment] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [VatNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IptNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [StatusId] [int] NULL,
    [IsPermissionToSpeak] [bit] NULL,
    [InsuranceProvider] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [InsuranceCoverNote] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [InsuranceInsuranceExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [InsurancePhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [InsuranceContract] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [IsInsuranceSubmissionCompleted] [bit] NULL,
    [RenterUserId] [int] NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsGlobalUserIgnored] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AgreementRenters] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO


DROP TABLE [dbo].[AgreementUsers]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AgreementUsers](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [IsRenter] [bit] NULL,
    [IsMainDriver] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsAdditionalDriver] [bit] NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [MidName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Surname] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [DOB] [datetime] NULL,
    [RenterId] [int] NULL,
    [FranchiseId] [int] NULL,
    [MainDriverId] [int] NULL,
    [AdditionalDriverId] [int] NULL,
    [RentalType] [int] NULL,
    [RenterType] [int] NULL,
    [RenterCompanyType] [smallint] NULL,
    [CompanyAccountNo] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [CompanyName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [CompanyDetail] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [StatusId] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreatedUserId] [int] NULL,
    [ModifiedUserId] [int] NULL,
    [PostCode] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [PhoneNo] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Street] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [LicenceNo] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [Sources] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IsApprovedAcountHolder] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceIsUkAddress] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [House] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [Village] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [int] NULL,
    [County] [int] NULL,
    [Town] [int] NULL,
    [CountryName] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [LicenceDetails] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceType] [int] NULL,
    [LicenceIssuedBy] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LicenceIssuedCountry] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [LicenceTestPassDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LicenceExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [LicenceSeen] [bit] NULL,
    [WebCheck] [bit] NULL,
    [ETDSeen] [bit] NULL,
    [CopyMade] [bit] NULL,
    [LicenceGroups] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [TownName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [CountyName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Occupation] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OccEmploymentType] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [OccName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [OccPhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [OccPostcode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [OccHouse] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [OccStreet] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [OccVillage] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [OccCountry] [int] NULL,
    [OccTown] [int] NULL,
    [OccVerified] [bit] NULL,
    [OccIsUkAddress] [bit] NULL,
    [OccTownName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [OccCountyName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [OccCountryName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Identification] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [IsRenterMainDriver] [bit] NULL,
    [HasMedicalIssue] [bit] NULL,
    [HasAccident] [bit] NULL,
    [HasConviction] [bit] NULL,
    [HasEverRefusedInsurance] [bit] NULL,
    [HasVehicleOrTrailerForCarriage] [bit] NULL,
    [OccCounty] [int] NULL,
    [Note] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ContactPostCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactAddressType] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactAddress1] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactAddress2] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactAddress3] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactCountry] [int] NULL,
    [ContactCounty] [int] NULL,
    [ContactTown] [int] NULL,
    [ContactMethod] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [ContactIsUkAddress] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [ContactTownName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactCountyName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [ContactCountryName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [CoiInsuranceCompany] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CoiPolicyNumber] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CoiContactName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CoiExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [CoiPhone] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [CoiCertificateCopy] [bit] NULL,
    [BKIsOwnInsurance] [bit] NULL,
    [isHighRiskUser] [bit] NULL,
    [HighRiskUsrComment] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [VatNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IptNo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [IsPermissionToSpeak] [bit] NULL,
    [InsuranceProvider] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [InsuranceCoverNote] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [InsuranceInsuranceExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [InsurancePhone] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [InsuranceContract] [varchar](250) NULL,
    [IsInsuranceSubmissionCompleted] [bit] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AgreementUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I tried to optimize the query with same results.

please see my query. I used two inner join by using the same derived tables which is fine.

Our client is now experiencing the slow performance issues by using below query.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCommonList]
@firstName nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@surName nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@title nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@companyName nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@phone nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@email nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@country nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@county nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@town nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@postcode nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@isHighRiskUser bit = NULL,
@note nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@franchiseId int = null,
@renterType int = NULL,
@Take int = 0,
@Skip int = 0
AS
BEGIN

declare @PageSize int = @Take;
declare @PageNumber int = @Skip;

Select tblD.Id as 'Id', [dbo].ConvertToEncryptedId(tblD.Id) as 'EncId',
(CASE
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.RenterType, 0) = 3 THEN
ISNULL(tblD.CompanyName, '')
ELSE
ISNULL(tblD.FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(tblD.Surname, '')
END) as 'RenterAccountHolderFullName',

ISNULL(tblD.RenterPhone, '') as 'RenterPhone',
ISNULL(tblD.RenterEmail, '') as 'RenterEmail',
ISNULL(tblD.PostCode, '') as 'LicencePostCode',
ISNULL(tblD.CountryName, '') as 'CountryName',
ISNULL(tblD.CountryName, '') as 'CountyName',
ISNULL(tblD.TownName, '') as 'TownName',
ISNULL(tblD.ContactPostCode, '') as 'ContactPostCode',

(CASE
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.RenterType,0) = 3 THEN
'Company'
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.RenterType,0) = 1 THEN
'Individual / Sole Trade'
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.RenterType,0) = 2 THEN
'Individual / Sole Trade'
ELSE
'N/A'
END) as 'RenterTypeName',

ISNULL(tblD.isHighRiskUser, 0) as 'IshighRiskRenter',

(CASE
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.isHighRiskUser, 0) = 1 THEN
'Yes'
ELSE
'No'
END) as 'HighRiskUsrTxt',

ISNULL(tblD.HighRiskUsrComment, '') as 'HighRiskUsrComment',
ISNULL(tblD.CompanyAccountNo, '') as 'RenterCompanyAcNumber',
ISNULL(tblD.CompanyName, '') as 'RenterCompanyName',
ISNULL(tblD.CompanyDetail, '') as 'RenterCompanyDetails',
ISNULL(tblD.FirstName, '') as 'RenterFirstName',
ISNULL(tblD.Surname, '') as 'RenterSurname',
ISNULL(tblD.FranchiseName, '') as 'FranchiseName',
ISNULL(tblD.RACount, 0) as 'RACount',
ISNULL(tblD.ResCount, 0) as 'ResCount',
count(ISNULL(tblD.Id, 0)) over() as 'TotalCount'

FROM
(
SELECT r.[Id],r.[LicenceDetails] AS LicenceDetailAvailable, r.[Id] RenterId,0 LookupRenterId,r.[LicenceIssuedBy],
r.[LicenceIssuedCountry],r.[LicenceExpiryDate],
r.[ETDSeen] IsETDSeen,r.[WebCheck] WebCheck,r.[LicenceSeen] LicenceSeen, r.[CopyMade] CopyMade,r.[RenterType] AS RenterType,
r.Sources ,
r.[Title] ,
r.[FirstName], r.[Surname] , r.[DOB] ,
r.[PhoneNo] AS RenterPhone,
r.[Email] AS RenterEmail,
r.[CompanyAccountNo],
r.[CompanyName],
r.[CompanyDetail],
r.[PostCode], r.[LicenceNo], r.[House], r.[Street] , r.[Village] ,
r.[Country], r.[County] , r.[Town] , (case when isnull(r.CountryName,'') = '-- Select Country --' then '' else r.CountryName end) CountryName, r.CountyName, r.TownName,
r.[ContactPostCode],
r.[ContactAddressType],
r.[ContactAddress1],
r.[ContactAddress2],
r.[ContactAddress3],
r.[ContactCountry],
r.[ContactCounty],
r.[ContactTown], r.[ContactMethod] ContactMethod, r.[ContactCountryName] ContactCountryName, r.[ContactCountyName] ContactCountyName, r.[ContactTownName] ContactTownName,
r.[Occupation] Occupation, r.[OccEmploymentType] OccEmploymentType, r.[OccName] OccName, r.[OccPhone] OccPhone, r.[OccPostcode] OccPostcode, r.[OccHouse] ,
r.[OccStreet] ,r.[OccVillage], r.[OccCountry] OccCountry, r.OccCountryName,r.[OccCounty] OccCounty, r.OccCountyName, r.[OccTown] OccTown, r.OccTownName, r.[OccVerified] OccVerified,
r.[IsApprovedAcountHolder] ,
r.[Identification],
r.[CoiInsuranceCompany] ,
r.[CoiPolicyNumber],
r.[CoiContactName] ,
r.[CoiExpiryDate],
r.[CoiPhone],
r.[CoiCertificateCopy] , r.[LicenceTestPassDate], r.[LicenceType],r.[LicenceGroups] ,
'' RenterAccountHolderFullName , r.[isHighRiskUser], r.[HighRiskUsrComment] HighRiskUsrComment, r.[VatNo] VatNo,r.[IptNo] IptNo, /*rt.RenterType*/ '' RenterTypeName,
/*fr.Name*/ '' FranchiseName,
r.[LicenceIsUkAddress], r.[ContactIsUkAddress], r.[OccIsUkAddress] ,
r.[MainDriverId] MainDriverId,'' OccVerifiedText,r.[FranchiseId],
r.IsPermissionToSpeak , r.InsuranceProvider, r.InsuranceCoverNote, r.InsuranceInsuranceExpiryDate, r.InsurancePhone, r.InsuranceContract, r.IsInsuranceSubmissionCompleted,
r.Note,ra.RACount RACount, res.ResCount ResCount,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.[Id] ORDER BY r.[Id] desc) AS RowNum
FROM AgreementUsers r WITH (NOLOCK)
left join (Select tblRA.Id,tblRA.UserId,
count(tblRA.Id) OVER (
PARTITION BY tblRA.UserId /*tblRA.Id*/ Order by tblRA.UserId desc
) RACount FROM
(Select distinct ba.Id,ar.RenterUserId UserId
from BookingAgreements ba with (nolock)
join AgreementRenters ar with (nolock) on ba.Id = ar.AgreementId
where ba.FranchiseId = @franchiseId and ba.StatusId = 1 and isnull(ba.RentalAgreementId,'') <> ''
UNION
Select distinct ba.Id,ad.MainDriverUserId UserId
from BookingAgreements ba with (nolock)
join AgreementDrivers ad with (nolock) on ba.Id = ad.AgreementId
where ba.FranchiseId = @franchiseId and ba.StatusId = 1 and isnull(ba.RentalAgreementId,'') <> '') tblRA) ra on ra.UserId = r.Id

left join (Select tblRes.Id,tblRes.UserId,count(tblRes.Id) OVER (
PARTITION BY tblRes.UserId Order by tblRes.UserId desc
) ResCount FROM
(Select distinct ba.Id,ar.RenterUserId UserId
from BookingAgreements ba with (nolock)
join AgreementRenters ar with (nolock) on ba.Id = ar.AgreementId
where ba.FranchiseId = @franchiseId and ba.StatusId = 1 and isnull(ba.RentalAgreementId,'') = ''
UNION
Select distinct ba.Id,ad.MainDriverUserId UserId
from BookingAgreements ba with (nolock)
join AgreementDrivers ad with (nolock) on ba.Id = ad.AgreementId
where ba.FranchiseId = @franchiseId and ba.StatusId = 1 and isnull(ba.RentalAgreementId,'') = '') tblRes ) res on res.UserId = r.Id

Where
(isnull(@franchiseId,0) > 0 and r.FranchiseId = @franchiseId) and
(ISNULL(@firstName,'') = '' OR isnull(REPLACE(lower(FirstName),' ',''),'') like CONCAT(ISNULL(REPLACE(lower(@firstName),' ',''),''),'%')) AND
(ISNULL(@surName,'') = '' OR (isnull(REPLACE(lower(Surname),' ',''),'') like CONCAT(ISNULL(REPLACE(lower(@surName),' ',''),''),'%'))) AND
(ISNULL(@companyName,'') = '' OR isnull(REPLACE(lower(r.CompanyName),' ',''),'') like CONCAT(ISNULL(REPLACE(lower(@companyName),' ',''),''),'%'))
AND (ISNULL(@email,'') = '' OR r.[Email] = ISNULL(@email,''))
AND (ISNULL(@phone,'') = '' OR r.[PhoneNo] = ISNULL(@phone,''))
AND (ISNULL(@postcode,'') = '' OR r.[PostCode] = ISNULL(@postcode,''))
AND (ISNULL(@country,'') = '' OR replace(lower(r.[CountryName]),' ','') = ISNULL(replace(lower(@country),' ',''),''))
AND (ISNULL(@county,'') = '' OR replace(lower(r.[CountyName]),' ','') = ISNULL(replace(lower(@county),' ',''),''))
AND (ISNULL(@town,'') = '' OR replace(lower(r.[TownName]),' ','') = ISNULL(replace(lower(@town),' ',''),''))
AND (ISNULL(@note,'') = '' OR Replace(r.HighRiskUsrComment,' ','') like CONCAT('%',ISNULL(REPLACE(@note,' ',''),''),'%'))
AND (ISNULL(@renterType,'') = '' OR (ISNULL(@renterType,'') = 1 AND r.[RenterType] in (1,2)) OR (ISNULL(@renterType,'') = 3 AND r.[RenterType] = 3))
AND (ISNULL(@isHighRiskUser,'') = '' OR r.[isHighRiskUser] = @isHighRiskUser)
) tblD WHERE tblD.RowNum = 1
order by tblD.[Id] desc
OFFSET (@Take * @Skip) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @Take ROWS ONLY ;

END
```

and the query plan is mentioned below:

https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJlN1xuHi

and my new query which I developed using CTE is as follow:

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetCommonRenterListHOD]
@firstName nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@surName nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@title nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@companyName nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@phone nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@email nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@country nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@county nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@town nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@postcode nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@isHighRiskUser bit = NULL,
@note nvarchar(250) = NULL,
@franchiseId int = null,
@renterType int = NULL,
@Take int = 0,
@Skip int = 0
AS
BEGIN

declare @PageSize int = @Take;
declare @PageNumber int = @Skip;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
;WITH CTECount AS (
Select dr.Id, dr.AgreementStatus ,dr.RentalAgreementId,dr.UserId, dr.RACount, dr.ResCount, dr.FranchiseId
FROM
(
Select ba.Id,userDetail.UserId,ba.RentalAgreementId, ba.AgreementStatus, ba.FranchiseId,
ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by userDetail.UserId order by userDetail.UserId desc) RowNo ,
(case when ba.RentalAgreementId <> '' then Count(ba.Id)
OVER (Partition by (case when ba.RentalAgreementId <> '' then userDetail.UserId else 0 end)) else 0 end) RACount,
(case when ba.RentalAgreementId = '' then Count(ba.Id)
OVER (Partition by (case when ba.RentalAgreementId = '' then userDetail.UserId else 0 end)) else 0 end) ResCount
from BookingAgreements ba with (nolock)
outer apply
(
Select ar.AgreementId,ar.RenterUserId UserId, ar.FranchiseId
FROM
AgreementRenters ar with (nolock)
where ar.FranchiseId = ba.FranchiseId and ar.AgreementId = ba.Id
UNION
Select ad.AgreementId,ad.MainDriverUserId UserId, ad.FranchiseId
FROM AgreementDrivers ad with (nolock)
where ad.FranchiseId = ba.FranchiseId and ad.AgreementId = ba.Id
) userDetail
Where ba.FranchiseId = userDetail.FranchiseId and ba.AgreementStatus <> 2
) dr where dr.RowNo = 1
),
CTE_RecordRows AS(
Select tblD.Id,tblD.EncId,tblD.CompanyName,
tblD.CompanyAccountNo,
tblD.CompanyDetail,
tblD.FirstName, tblD.Surname,
tblD.RenterPhone ,
tblD.RenterEmail ,
tblD.PostCode,
tblD.CountyName,
tblD.CountryName,
tblD.TownName,
tblD.ContactPostCode,
tblD.RenterType,
tblD.isHighRiskUser,
tblD.HighRiskUsrComment,
tblD.FranchiseName FranchiseName,
tblD.RACount, tblD.ResCount,
tblD.FranchiseId
FROM
(SELECT r.Id ,
[dbo].ConvertToEncryptedId(r.Id) as 'EncId',
r.CompanyName,
r.CompanyAccountNo,
r.CompanyDetail,
r.FirstName, r.Surname,
r.PhoneNo RenterPhone,
r.Email RenterEmail,
r.PostCode,
r.CountyName,
(case when isnull(r.CountryName,'') = '-- Select Country --' then '' else r.CountryName end) CountryName,
r.TownName,
r.ContactPostCode,
r.RenterType,
r.isHighRiskUser,
r.HighRiskUsrComment,
frn.Name FranchiseName,
c.RACount,
c.ResCount,
r.FranchiseId
FROM AgreementUsers r WITH (NOLOCK)
inner join CTECount c on r.Id = c.UserId
inner join Franchise frn on r.FranchiseId = frn.Id
Where frn.Status_Id = 1 and
-- (isnull(@franchiseId,0) > 0 and r.FranchiseId = @franchiseId) and
(ISNULL(@firstName,'') = '' OR isnull(REPLACE(lower(FirstName),' ',''),'') like CONCAT(ISNULL(REPLACE(lower(@firstName),' ',''),''),'%')) AND
(ISNULL(@surName,'') = '' OR (isnull(REPLACE(lower(Surname),' ',''),'') like CONCAT(ISNULL(REPLACE(lower(@surName),' ',''),''),'%'))) AND
(ISNULL(@companyName,'') = '' OR isnull(REPLACE(lower(r.CompanyName),' ',''),'') like CONCAT(ISNULL(REPLACE(lower(@companyName),' ',''),''),'%'))
AND (ISNULL(@email,'') = '' OR r.[Email] = ISNULL(@email,''))
AND (ISNULL(@phone,'') = '' OR r.[PhoneNo] = ISNULL(@phone,''))
AND (ISNULL(@postcode,'') = '' OR r.[PostCode] = ISNULL(@postcode,''))
AND (ISNULL(@country,'') = '' OR replace(lower(r.[CountryName]),' ','') = ISNULL(replace(lower(@country),' ',''),''))
AND (ISNULL(@county,'') = '' OR replace(lower(r.[CountyName]),' ','') = ISNULL(replace(lower(@county),' ',''),''))
AND (ISNULL(@town,'') = '' OR replace(lower(r.[TownName]),' ','') = ISNULL(replace(lower(@town),' ',''),''))
AND (ISNULL(@note,'') = '' OR Replace(r.HighRiskUsrComment,' ','') like CONCAT('%',ISNULL(REPLACE(@note,' ',''),''),'%'))
AND (ISNULL(@renterType,'') = '' OR (ISNULL(@renterType,'') = 1 AND r.[RenterType] in (1,2)) OR (ISNULL(@renterType,'') = 3 AND r.[RenterType] = 3))
AND (ISNULL(@isHighRiskUser,'') = '' OR r.[isHighRiskUser] = @isHighRiskUser)
) tblD -- Where tblD.rowNo = 1
)

Select tblD.Id as 'Id', [dbo].ConvertToEncryptedId(tblD.Id) as 'EncId',
(CASE
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.RenterType, 0) = 3 THEN
ISNULL(tblD.CompanyName, '')
ELSE
ISNULL(tblD.FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(tblD.Surname, '')
END) as 'RenterAccountHolderFullName',

ISNULL(tblD.RenterPhone, '') as 'RenterPhone',
ISNULL(tblD.RenterEmail, '') as 'RenterEmail',
ISNULL(tblD.PostCode, '') as 'LicencePostCode',
ISNULL(tblD.CountryName, '') as 'CountryName',
ISNULL(tblD.CountryName, '') as 'CountyName',
ISNULL(tblD.TownName, '') as 'TownName',
ISNULL(tblD.ContactPostCode, '') as 'ContactPostCode',

(CASE
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.RenterType,0) = 3 THEN
'Company'
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.RenterType,0) = 1 THEN
'Individual / Sole Trade'
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.RenterType,0) = 2 THEN
'Individual / Sole Trade'
ELSE
'N/A'
END) as 'RenterTypeName',

ISNULL(tblD.isHighRiskUser, 0) as 'IshighRiskRenter',

(CASE
WHEN ISNULL(tblD.isHighRiskUser, 0) = 1 THEN
'Yes'
ELSE
'No'
END) as 'HighRiskUsrTxt',

ISNULL(tblD.HighRiskUsrComment, '') as 'HighRiskUsrComment',
ISNULL(tblD.CompanyAccountNo, '') as 'RenterCompanyAcNumber',
ISNULL(tblD.CompanyName, '') as 'RenterCompanyName',
ISNULL(tblD.CompanyDetail, '') as 'RenterCompanyDetails',
ISNULL(tblD.FirstName, '') as 'RenterFirstName',
ISNULL(tblD.Surname, '') as 'RenterSurname',
ISNULL(tblD.FranchiseName, '') as 'FranchiseName',
ISNULL(tblD.RACount, 0) as 'RACount',
ISNULL(tblD.ResCount, 0) as 'ResCount',
count(ISNULL(tblD.Id, 0)) over() as 'TotalCount',
ISNULL(tblD.FranchiseId, 0) as 'Franchise_Id'
FROM CTE_RecordRows tblD
order by tblD.[FranchiseName] asc
OFFSET (@Take * @Skip) ROWS
FETCH NEXT @Take ROWS ONLY OPTION (RECOMPILE);

END
```

and the query plan is mentioned below:

[https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=hkpsa1dbj](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkPsA1dBj)

Comment: Please don't link to files that need to be downloaded. Instead, copy the query plan XML and paste it in [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan), then link that in your Post please.

Comment: thank you but query plan xml is too large to enter in a above post. It is restricting the user to post.

Comment: 1. Indentation is your friend 2. It's impossible to know if your logic is correct without a data model/table definitions/etc. This question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: OK please see the table structure now in the main above post

Comment: I didn't say to put the plan XML directly in your post. Use the website I linked in my above comment instead.

Comment: OK please check here 
This is the actual plan of my newly developed query
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkPsA1dBj
and this is the first query plan 
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJlN1xuHi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### stop right there

Before you spend any more time on the query as written, you need to understand that you're writing this type of query in the second worst way possible, and incorporating a lot of other painful anti-patterns that will haunt this query for the rest of its days.

### optional parameters

The optional parameter handling is never going to perform well as written. Even with a recompile hint, you're boned here for a lot of reasons, but we'll get to those later.

In a better world, you'd use parameterized dynamic SQL to generate your where clause.

```
DECLARE
    @s nvarchar(MAX) = N'',
    @DisplayName nvarchar(40) = N'Eggs McLaren'


SET @s = N'
SELECT
    c = COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM dbo.Users AS u
WHERE 1 = 1
';

IF @DisplayName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @s += N'
AND u.DisplayName = @DisplayName';
END;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql
    @s,
    N'@DisplayName nvarchar(40)',
    @DisplayName;
```

See:

- [Handling Optional Parameters](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/software-vendor-mistakes-with-sql-server-handling-optional-parameters/)
- [Writing Unsafe Dynamic SQL](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/software-vendor-mistakes-with-sql-server-writing-unsafe-dynamic-sql/)

### but even if you do that...

You're doing other things that will prevent SQL Server from efficiently using indexes. Some folks will call it "[SARGability](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/sargability-week-wrap-up/)"

```
OR isnull(REPLACE(lower(FirstName),' ',''),'') 
like CONCAT(ISNULL(REPLACE(lower(@firstName),' ',''),''),'%'))
```

Doing it on the parameter value (@firstName) isn't so harmful, but applying functions to columns in joins and where clauses means that you'll end up, at best, scanning the entire index and applying a predicate, and at worst scanning the entire index and having to filter data out way later in the plan.

If this is a data quality issue, consider addressing it either when data is brought into the table, or via a [computed column](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/adding-computed-columns/) in the table to aid searches.

### and then that UDF

I'm not sure what this function does, but unless you're on SQL Server 2019 and in compatibility level 150 (query plan XML indicates 130), and it doesn't do anything that flaunts the [Book of Froid](https://%5Bdbo%5D.ConvertToEncryptedId), it's going to add to your performance woes:

```
[dbo].ConvertToEncryptedId
```

Consider either rewriting the UDF to an inline table valued type, or putting your data into a #temp table and calling the UDF when you select out of it later to produce final results.

- [Rewriting UDFs](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/ctes-are-useful-for-rewriting-scalar-functions/)
- [Avoiding UDFs](https://erikdarlingdata.com/a-trick-for-working-around-scalar-udf-performance-issues/)

### complexity is not a virtue

I'm not sure where the developer fetish for writing everything in a single query comes from, but it's a foolish one. Consider [breaking your query up](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/breaking-up-big-queries/) into #temp tables at some of the logical stopping points, like derived tables, etc.

### paging, etc.

For unpredictable search queries, consider [using nonclustered column store indexes](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/considerations-for-paging-queries-in-sql-server-with-batch-mode-dont-use-offset-fetch/) to improve overall performance and avoid over-indexing scenarios. Your query plan XML indicates you're on SQL Server 2019, so they should be a decent option for you.

Comment: thank you very much Erik Darling.  Great tips have been provided. i try these now